# Updating a column of all rows in a table takes a long time

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have a table in a `aurora postgres` database with 20 million records.

I used a script to insert this 20 million records with some dummy values, and it took about 20 minutes (script uses multiple connections in parallel to insert).

Now if I execute following query on the database, it takes more than an hour to complete.

```
UPDATE my_table set my_column = 'some_value';
```

Why does this update take more time than it took to insert all records to the table? Is there a way to optimize the update?

Comment: UPDATES take longer that INSERTS because they are more complex operations. For a start, an UPDATE has to find the record to update whereas an INSERT doesn't care about any existing records (ignoring PK clashes, missing FK records, etc)

Comment: PostGreSQL is known to use a DELETE + INSERT when an UPDATE is done. This made the process of UPDATING slower than creating new values...